# Coefficient of Determination and Standard Error of the Model

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

Background explaining standard concepts and standard terminology used in linear regression and analysis of variance:

It will be supposed that one has data points $(X_i,Y_i),\, i = 1,\ldots,n.$

The average $Y$ value for a given $X$ value (which need not be one of the $n$ observed $X$ values), as estimated by least squares, is denoted $\widehat Y.$ The $i$th fitted value $\widehat Y_i$ is the value of $\widehat Y$ when $X$ is the $i$th observed $X$ value $X_i.$

The total corrected sum of squares is $\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\overline Y)^2$ where $\overline Y = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i.$

The residual sum of squares, also called the unexplained sum of squares, is $\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \widehat Y_i)^2.$

The explained sum of squares is $\sum_{i=1}^n (\widehat Y_i - \overline Y)^2.$

The nature of least squares entails that the total (corrected) sum of squares is the sum of the explained and the unexplained sums of squares. "Corrected" means that $\overline Y$ has been subtracted from all of the $Y$ values before squaring.

The coefficient of determination $R^2$ is what proportion of the total (corrected) sum of squares is is explained, i.e. the explained divided by the total. (It is called $R^2$ because when one is simply fitting a straight line, it is the square of the correlation. When fitting a plane or a polynomial, etc., it is not the square of the correlation but it is still conventional to call it $R^2.$)

The $F$ statistic for fitting the null hypothesis that the sample was taken from a population in which the slope of the line is $0$ is
$$
F = \frac{\text{explained sum of squares}/1}{\text{unexplained sum of squares}/(n-2)}.
$$
(The denominators $1$ and $n-2$ are "degrees of freedom"; if one were fitting a more complicated model a number other than $1$ would appear in the numerator. The unexplained sum of squares has $n-2$ degrees of freedom because the vector $(Y_i - \widehat Y_i : i = 1,\ldots,n)$ satisfies two linear constraints: that the sum of its entries is $0$ and that the sum of the products of its components with the respective $X_i$ is $0.$) (One rejects that null hypothesis if $F$ is improbably large.)

There's the textbook; below is the question as the original poster wrote it.

---

i need some help.

$\hat{Y} = 5+2X$

F(Stat.) = 25

$n=102$

$\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}{(Y_{i}-\bar{Y}})^2 = 10$

i got this outputs but i need to find Coefficient of Determination and  Standard Error of the Model with using this outputs.

Comment: Those who closed this question used a boilerplate notice that says: "Please provide additional context [...] Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions [...]" I've added background and relevant definitions that will make the question clear to those who did not know standard terminology of linear regression and anova that suffices to make the question comprehensible.

Comment: i think i tried my best but in this website they just want to "professional posts". I got outputs as i said and i wanted to learn how to solve this question but whatever. Thank you for tried to answer to my question.  Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that $\text{“}F\text{''}$ is intended to mean the $F$ statistic for testing the null hypothesis that the population slope is $0.$ Then you have:
$$
25 = F= \frac{\text{explained sum of squares}/1}{\text{unexplained sum of squares}/(102-2)}.
$$
And
$$
R^2 = \frac{\text{explained sum of squares}}{\text{total (corrected) sum of squares}} = \frac{\text{explained sum of squares}}{10}.
$$
I will abbreviate some things:
$$
25 = \frac e {u/100}. \qquad R^2 = \frac e {10}. \qquad e+u = 10.
$$
So
\begin{align}
& 25u = 100 e \\[6pt]
& 10R^2= e \\[6pt]
& e+u=10
\end{align}
You have three linear equations in three unknown quantities, and what you want is $R^2,$ the coefficient of determination.

(You get $R^2 = 0.2$.)